# jQuery remove attribute won't work if multiple clicks in fast speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some check boxes on my page. Through jQuery change function I am appending a div if checkbox is checked. If checkbox is not checked remove that div. It works fine if clicks in slow speed. Whenever multiple click attempts happens in fast speed it don't remove the div. It keeps appending the div multiple time. Can someone please help me fix this? Following is my attempt.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#include_addon_checkbox_<?PHP echo $addon_ids; ?>').change(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){

    var summary_div = '<div class="sidebar_addon" id="sidebar_addon_<?PHP echo $addon_ids ?>"><div class="addon-content"><?PHP echo str_replace("_", " ", $addons_keys) ?><p><?PHP echo $addon_package_name; ?> <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_<?PHP echo $addon_ids; ?>"><span>(more details)</span></a></p></div><div class="addon-price">$ <?PHP echo $addon_package_price; ?></span></div>';

    $('#addons_container').append(summary_div);
    $('#sidebar_addon_<?PHP echo $addon_ids ?>').hide().slideDown(750);
}
else {
    $('#sidebar_addon_<?PHP echo $addon_ids ?>').slideUp(750, function(){ $(this).remove(); });
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please, provide a jsfiddle, it'll help us a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is about your animation timings. You can lover animation times to 200-300ms. Or disable all checkboxes until your animation has ended. Then enable them.

Comment: I think your answer resolve my problem. Because when I remove the animation function it is working fine. But I really want to keep the animation. Can you please tell me how I can disable the check boxes while animation is in process? I would appreciate if you will put some piece of code within my original code to disable the checkboxes.

Comment: Yes i can but can you give me some proper code of your work? Withoud php and no necessary thing. I have to test on jsfiddle or similar site. Or maybe you put your codes on jsfiddle and give me link.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the php variable's problem.
you can try this:

```html
<script>
    var addon_ids = "<?PHP echo $addon_ids ?>";
    var content = .....;
    and so on......;
</script>
<script>
    $(function(){
       $('#include_addon_checkbox_'+addon_ids ).change(function(){
           add you code.
       })
    })
</script>
```

Before loading the page, the php variable assigned to the js variable.
then jquery load it.